# How to disable ActiveAndroid LruCache

Tags: android, activeandroid, android-lru-cache

Does anyone know how to disable ActiveAndroid default behavior of caching object models in LruCache?

I want to disable entirely from my project. I have been able to clear the cache manually using **Cache.clear();** but I need to keep doing it every time I need to clear it. I just want to disable all together via configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation on this matter so I dug into the code and end up doing the below workaround.

It seems there is no way to disable caching in ActiveAndroid but they offer a way to set the **maxSize** of the **LruCache** via the Configuration class. So I initialized ActiveAndroid like this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration.Builder(this).setCacheSize(1).create();
ActiveAndroid.initialize(config);
```

Setting the CacheSize to 1 sort of prevents the addition of Model objects to the cache so it seems to works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

public final void evictAll ()

Clear the cache, calling entryRemoved(boolean, K, V, V) on each removed entry.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. But what I need is to disable caching altogether and not on a case by case manner.